# how to get a universal app to show up in both sections of the app store

Tags: iphone, ipad, store, universal

I just released a universal update to what had previously been an iPhone app.  But it's only showing up in the iPhone section of the store, even when I search for it on an iPad.  It does have the little plus sign indicating a universal app, and it does load the right screenshots for the iPad, but it doesn't show up in the iPad section of the store.

Do I need to do something?

Adam

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Might want to wait a day or two. It should show in both sections, but every change in AppStore takes some time until all balanced AppStore servers get an update.

Comment: yep.  that's exactly what happened.

Comment: @adamD - How long did it end up taking for you?